# Using jQuery inside of a React render function

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, reactjs, jsx

I have the following React render function:

```
   render: function () {
        return (
            <Popup onClose={this.props.onClose}>
                <Form entity="strategy" edit="/strategies/edit/" add="/strategies/add/">
                    <h2>Create/Edit Strategy</h2>
                    <StrategyForm pending={this.state.pending} formData={this.state.data} />
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                        <Assisting />
                    </div>
                </Form>
            </Popup>
        );
    }
```

I would like to make the h2 heading be based on the body class, so my question is...can I do this?

```
    render: function () {
        return (
            <Popup onClose={this.props.onClose}>
                <Form entity="strategy" edit="/strategies/edit/" add="/strategies/add/">
                    if ( $('body').hasClass("this") ) {
                     <h2>Create This Strategy</h2>
                    } else {
                     <h2>Create Another Strategy</h2>
                    }
                    <StrategyForm pending={this.state.pending} formData={this.state.data} />
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                        <Assisting />
                    </div>
                </Form>
            </Popup>
        );
    }
```

If this is a terrible idea, can someone tell me what is a better way to do this in React?

Comment: It's probably a bad idea (there's definitely no reason to use jQuery for it), but what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @tobiasandersen I thought so.  I am just trying to return two different headers based on body class.

Comment: While it's possible to do just what you ask, it's not the "React way" of doing it. Are you using React only for this component? When, how and why do you set the body class?

Comment: @tobiasandersen There are two sections of the web app.  The appearance of the site is based on the body class.  So there is only the possibility of two body classes.  I use react for many components and most of the front-end.  But I was having trouble with this piece.  I was not able to use jQuery as shown above so came here for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has already been noted in some of the comments on the OP, you *could* do it, but it's not really the "React" way.

A better solution would probably be to pass a `prop` into the usage of your component or have a flag on the state of your component -- then use that prop/flag to render.

Pseudocode:

```
render() {
    return (
        if (this.props.someProp) {
            <h2>Create this Strategy</h2>
        } else {
            <h2>Create this Strategy</h2>
        }
    );
}
```

IMO using jQuery in the component methods is fine (e.g. `componentDidMount()`, or other event/utility methods) but usually you'll want to avoid this in `render()`. The whole purpose of React components is maintaining state, so on-the-fly usage of jQuery like your example defeats that idea.

---

Let's say for example you're rendering your component this way:

```
ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById('some-div'));
```

You can pass properties to your component:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <MyComponent someProp={true} />, 
    document.getElementById('some-div')
);
```

Or in your case:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <MyComponent someProp={$('body').hasClass("this")} />, 
    document.getElementById('some-div')
);
```

...something like that. It's an over-simplified example (not tested, so beware syntax errors) but that should help explain my thought process.

---

Alternatively, you use the `componentDidMount()` method on your class.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ 
        someProp : $('body').hasClass("this")
    });
}
```

and then in `render()` check against `this.state.someProp`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I did not write the React function but am now working inside of it.  Can you give me a little insight into how to create that prop based on body class.  Sorry I'm fuzzy on how this works.

Comment: Updated with examples :-)